# how to automatically init an object after jetty setup?

Tags: java, rest, jetty, jax-rs

My java application starts a jetty server container.

Is there any "after init" method that jetty can call after it's up

that will construct a specific BL object and call one of its methods?

This is my code to init jetty:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SdkServiceConfig.s.initLog();

    logger.error("testing log");
    final int port = 8083;
```

...

```
    webappContext.setExtractWAR(false);
    handlers.addHandler(webappContext);

    // Adding the handlers to the server.
    jettyServer.setHandler(handlers);


    try {
        jettyServer.start();
        jettyServer.join();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("failed to init jetty server", ex);
        System.out.println(ex);
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } finally {
        jettyServer.destroy();
    }
}
```

and then i call specific url to trigger my server state initialization.

Server.java

```
@Path("/waitRequests")
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public void waitRequests() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("waitRequests");


    PubSubFactory pubSubFactory = new PubSubFactory();
    pubSubFactory.init(SdkServiceConfig.s.GCP_PROJECT_ID, new File(SdkServiceConfig.s.SDK_PUBSUB_CLIENT_SECRET));
```

I wish it would be something like:

```
@Path("/sdk-service")
public class SdkOperation {

    private final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = LoggingUtils.getLogger();

    private final CofmanService cofmanService;

    //    private SdkRequestRepo sdkRequestRepo;
    private CustomPublisher resultPublisher;

    public SdkOperation() throws Exception {
        this(new CofmanServiceNet(), null);
    }



Server server = new Server();
server.waitRequests()
```

Comment: Not clear on what you mean by "after init".  That sounds like the state of the Jetty `LifeCycle` before you start Jetty (or one of its components).

Comment: i have added code. do you know how?

Comment: Looks like you are using JAX-RS.  I adjusted the tags to make more sense for the scope of your question as the solution will be within JAX-RS (not Jetty or the Servlet spec).  If you know the specific library providing JAX-RS for you, then add that tag too (such as [tag:resteasy])